# Ctx.db.mutation."updateAccepted" is not a function.. Mutation isn't generated by Prisma

Tags: reactjs, graphql, next.js, prisma, prisma-graphql

I try to make a graphql mutation for updating an item from my existing db. Still I got an error when i try to executing this mutation.

I added the "accepted" to the Item:

I tried to deploy my schema but doesnt effect anything..

```
type Item {
  id: ID! @id
  title: String!
  image: String
  largeImage: String
  price: Int!
  user: User!
  accepted: String!
}
```

After this I made the mutation:

```
type Mutation {
  updateAccepted(id: ID!): Item!
}
```

Then i wrote the resolver:

```
async updateAccepted(parent, args, ctx, info) {
    // 1. Check if the person is logged in
    const { userId } = ctx.request;
    if (!userId) {
      throw new Error('You must be signed in');
    }
    // 2. find the item
    const item = await ctx.db.mutation.updateAccepted(
      {
        where: { id: args.id },
        data: {
          accepted: 1
        }
      },
      info
    );

    // 3. Return the item
    return item;
  },
```

When I execute this function inside the playground i get this error

```
{
  "data": null,
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "ctx.db.mutation.updateAccepted is not a function",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 10,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "updateAccepted"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Kinda clueless atm, please help dev in need :)

Comment: It doesn't seem like a problem with your graphql definitions or with prisma, but rather you db driver. What are you using to query the DB?

Comment: GraphQL Yoga Server, I build my website based on the Advance React GraphQL course of Wes Bos

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved. Issue was that I had to call `updateItem` instead of `updateAccepted`. The mutation is on type `Item`... not `accepted`..

```
async updateAccepted(parent, args, ctx, info) {
    const { id, accepted } = args;
    // 1. Check if the person is logged in
    const { userId } = ctx.request;
    if (!userId) {
      throw new Error('You must be signed in');
    }
    // 2. find the item
    return ctx.db.mutation.updateItem(
      {
        data: { accepted },
        where: { id: args.id }
      },
      info
    );
  },
```

Happy days